# Cannot add new data to state that contains an array

Tags: reactjs

I have:

```
[state, setState] = useState([
{ 
item: apple,
color: red,
},{ 
item: banana,
color:yellow,
}])
```

I want to add the following to the array :

```
{ 
item: grape,
color: purple
}
```

I have tried

```
 setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState,  newObj }))
```

and

```
setState({ state: state.concat(newObj) });
```

But the the data is not being added to the state

Comment: Should be `([ ...prevState,  newObj ])`

Comment: `setState((prevState) => ([ ...prevState,  newObj ]))` - replace the  `{}` with `[]` in the setState as you initialized an array and not an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the ways you tried are almost correct but not quite.

```js
// your updating the state to an object and not an array
setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState,  newObj }))
// Instead you should be spreading onto an array
setState((prevState) => ([ ...prevState,  newObj ]))
```

The other way is of similar issue.

```js
// Your setting the state to an object which contains the property state
setState({ state: state.concat(newObj) });
// update the state to an array of the concat array
setState(state.concat(newObj));
```

See https://react.dev/learn/updating-arrays-in-state for more info on correctly updating state on arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You you have array of items as your initial state, but later you are setting an object as a new state.
In order to add new data you have to use array (square brackets):

```
setState((prevState) => ([ ...prevState,  newObj ]));
```